# How to run a docker compose image downloaded from docker hub (in Windows 10 w/ Docker Toolbox)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I want to run this docker hub image locally: https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app (which normally runs with a npm start and gradlew) in W10home using Docker ToolBox (and it works fine)

I followed the instructions at: https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/
and try to run a: **$ docker-compose -f jhipster-sample-app/prod.yml up** , but it gives me this error (although the image is there):

```
usuario@DESKTOP-GTCQCAR MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker-compose -f jhipster-sample-app/prod.yml up
ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\jhipster-sample-app/prod.yml'
```

NOTE: I also tried changing the tag, but with the same result. Why is it not finding the image that is for sure there?

I also tried to Quick launch: Run a simple jhipster application directly with Docker, in development profile: **$ docker container run -d -p 8080:8080 -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev jhipster/jhipster-sample-app**

But, I could not access to the application at http://localhost:8080 (though the container is created and running).

I even try to run it: **$ docker run jhipster/jhipster-sample-app** getting this error:

```
 2019-01-31 09:33:05.215  INFO 1 --- [           main] 

i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationApp     : Starting JhipsterSampleApplicationApp on 596e926cb096 with PID 1 (/app.war started by root in /)
2019-01-31 09:33:05.252  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationApp     : The following profiles are active: prod
2019-01-31 09:33:37.773 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

But I can run other images like **$ docker run hello-world**

So I feel kind of lost here and I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks all! I'm new to Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app, you need to start the other containers such as the database.  These are not packaged in the app container.

```
git clone https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app.git
cd jhipster-sample-app
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d
```

This will load the config from [app.yml](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/21af1441005f52cf1c0fd1c598f722b2ebb6c2d9/src/main/docker/app.yml) and start both the app and database containers.

Comment: The -d makes the difference, but is not in docker compose documentation (or in Jhipster docs): https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/  What is the -d for? Thanks Jon

Comment: The `-d` simply starts the containers in detached mode (in the background).  It's not required.  You can read in detail by running `docker-compose up --help` (or see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)